# Data Comparison Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a project for our accounting department and I got stuck with the below query. We have two tables in a MSAccess DB with tax data in them. The process is that we receive a file on a monthly basis with new tax info. The only time data changes is when tax updates are made but governmental entities. So, on any give month we can have 5 changes or 5000.

The goal of the below query is two compare the new data with the data from last month (in two separate tables). However, I am getting prompted to enter criteria and I am not sure why. Ideally, the query will run and return any differences between the two tables.

```
SELECT newtax.[zipcode],
       newtax.city,
       newtax.county,
       newtax.state,
       newtax!combinedsalestax - oldtax!combinedsalestax AS Change,
       newtax.combinedsalestax,
       oldtax.combinedsalestax
FROM   oldtax
       INNER JOIN newtax
               ON ( oldtax.[zipcode] = newtax.[zipcode] )
                  AND ( oldtax.city = newtax.city )
                  AND ( oldtax.county = newtax.county )
WHERE  (( ( [newtax]![combinedsalestax] - [oldtax]![combinedsalestax] ) <> 0));
```

I am also open to suggestion on how to modify this query completely as I am assuming there is a better way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get rid of the exclamation marks, they are for controls, not fields. A check for null (Nz) might be a good idea.

```
SELECT newtax.[zipcode],
       newtax.city,
       newtax.county,
       newtax.state,
       newtax.combinedsalestax - oldtax.combinedsalestax AS Change,
       newtax.combinedsalestax,
       oldtax.combinedsalestax
FROM   oldtax
       INNER JOIN newtax
               ON ( oldtax.[zipcode] = newtax.[zipcode] )
                  AND ( oldtax.city = newtax.city )
                  AND ( oldtax.county = newtax.county )
WHERE  Nz(newtax.combinedsalestax,0) <> Nz(oldtax.combinedsalestax,0)
```

If you are still prompted for a parameter, it is likely you have a misspelled field name.

Comment: It was indeed a space in a field name that was causing the prompts. Thanks for the advice. I have tried the query as you have it and I am strangely not returning any results. I know the datasets are different as I have manually changed some for testing purposes.

Comment: I have made another small change, but I basically copied your query. Does you original return records, because I cannot see how one would work and the other not work. Theoretically, the changes I made should turn up more differences, not fewer.

Comment: I believe the problem was not with the original query. Basically this was all generated because our import specification file was missing. So a new one had to be created. The access DB was still in 2000 format and the new spec file was created in 2010. I exported all the data into a 2010 DB and it worked perfectly. Not sure why...but that resolved the issue. EDIT: Thanks for your help I have not yet changed the query as it started work but gave you best answer anyway!

Comment: Well I am glad you got it sorted.